# Is there any role of Operating system in C++ compilation process

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++ and I was going through this article : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2v07M4Gy/

I have few doubts,

- Does Operating System has to anything when the *.o file and *.exe files are created by compiler or is the architecture of compiler(for that OS) that controls whole compilation process.
- Secondly, if I am working on Windows OS with two different CPU architectures.
  Now, I create a sample.exe using C++ on machine1 with intel processor.
  Then I  try to execute this sample.exe in machine2 with some other CPU architecture.
  my question is how will same 'sample.exe' file will execute the same instructions on two different CPU architectures.

Sorry for any wrong terminology used, if any.

Comment: Regarding your second question, AMD and Intel both implement the same x86 (or x86_64) architecture (assuming you target a "standard" PC).

Comment: The compiler will compile it targeting that architecture, the system itself doesn't take any part in the compilation process other than storing the file generated by the compiler in the hard drive when it's done. In some cases you can even tell the compiler you want the generated binary to target a different architecture.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am talking about any two different CPU architectures...and thanks for the info though.

Comment: The operating system schedules the compiler process, manages all its input and output, ... Unclear what you're asking, or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the compilers job (in cooperation with a linker that joins the different object files and libraries into the actual executable) to produce an executable file that can be loaded on the system. Obviously, the compiler is a process that executes on the machine that hosts the compiler, and has help of services to access files, allocate memory, and so on, like any other process that executes on the machine. The "host" may be the same OS as the target for the application, or in an embedded system, you'd use a "cross-compiler", where you compile your code on say a windows-machine, and then install it onto your small dedicated computer - but for common software development, the compiler lives on the same system that will execute the code.

The loading process is, on most systems, an integrated part of the OS itself. In an embedded system, the loading process may be "program the resulting binary into memory, and put the code in the right place so your code takes care of starting the entire system", rather than the windows/linux style of loading the program code from a file into RAM and then jumping to it.

As long as the processors involved are sufficiently compatible, the executable will work for multiple processor models, potentially from different manufacturers. AMD and Intel both make processors that use Intel ia32 (aka x86), and more recently, AMDs x86-64 instruction sets, so aside from a small number of "extensions" that each manufacturer have to their processors, these processors are designed with the intent of "doing the same thing for the same set of instructions". The details of exactly HOW those instructions are executed vary between manufacturers (and models withín the range), but the outcome is guaranteed to be the same.

Other processor architectures (ARM, MIPS, VAX, PowerPC, HP-PA, Itanium) are not sufficiently close that another processor architecture will be able to execute it. There have been projects to run processor architecture A on architecture B via some kind of simulator, but this is often quite a lot slower, and quite a difficult task to get right - it's a big software project to write such a thing to work efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler controls what output you get (that is why [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) is possible), however it may or may not need system libraries/other resources to perform compilation successfully. Regarding your second question, both Intel and AMD processors implement the same instruction set ([x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) or [x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)), so the same machine code can be executed on them even though their internal structure is very different. If you wanted to use a CPU with a different instruction set (for example an ARM) you would need to recompile for that specific CPU.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler takes in source code - Ascii files - and turns them into machine code, binary executable files. Basically that process is platform agnostic, we're mapping one set of bits to another set of bits. But there might need to be a few OS calls to tag the resulting executable as "executable code".

For the second question, binary executables for Windows ought to be portable to other copies of Windows, even if they run on slightly different chips. The chips are designed to be binary compatible. It doesn't always quite work out however, sometimes one version of Windows will refuse to execute programs produced on another, earlier version. If you are talking about Windows mobile, then recompilation will be necessary - the chips in mobile phones are not compatible with PC boxes.

Comment: While a few compilers might take in files with the ASCII encoding, many default to a different encoding and allow the "source character set" to be specified. (But, okay, most such encodings would encode a subset of characters in common with ASCII with the same bytes that ASCII encodes them. So, you can pass off a file written with one encoding to be read with a different encoding if the content is so aligned.) Some compilers also consume non-source files (such as string resources) that have other rules. And—back to the OS—source files reference other files so must allow legal file path chars.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, every program uses operating system services, notably (indirectly) thru [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). For example, input/output, so reading or writing files, goes thru the operating system.

> Does Operating System has to anything when the *.o file and *.exe files are created by compiler or is the architecture of compiler(for that OS) that controls whole compilation process.

The compiler is creating and writing these `*.o` [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) and `*.exe` [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). It uses the operating system to do so.

When something is starting an executable, the operating system is invoked for that.

> Secondly, if I am working on Windows OS with two different CPU architectures.

AMD & Intel processors are the *same* x86 architecture (and a binary for AMD can run on Intel and vice versa)   Of course, if you have some ARM based computer (e.g. a Raspberry Pi) and if you got a Windows OS for it, you have two different computer architectures.